# AngularJS Factory won't work (Yeoman)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman-generator-angular

I am trying to learn AngularJS and are therefor making a very simple Angular app.
Everything was working, until i tried to split up my controller by making a factory (which i imagine is the right way to do it). Now my main/index only shows an empty page, where as before the factory was implemented the form was showing. I can't figure it out! 
NOTE: I am using Yeoman's Angular setup.

FOLDERSTRUCTURE:

- Controller

  - about.js
  - conversion.js
  - main.js
- app.js

Here is my main/index page (main.html):

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as measure">

<form role="form">
  <h2>BMI udregner:</h2>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Vægt</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="measure.weight">
    <select ng-model="measure.inMass" class="form-control input-sm" >
      <option ng-repeat="m in measure.mases">{{m}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Højde</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="measure.height">
  </div>

  <div>
    <b>Total:</b> 
    <span>
      {{ measure.total(measure.inMass) }}
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

My Controller (main.js):

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name measureBmiApp.controller:MainCtrl
 * @description
 * # MainCtrl
 * Controller of the measureBmiApp
 */
angular.module('measureBmiApp', ['Conversion'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['weightConverter', function(weightConverter) {
    this.height = 180;
    this.weight = 90; 
    this.inMass = 'kg';
    this.mases  = weightConverter.mases;

    this.total = function total(outMass) {
        return weightConverter.convertMass(this.weight / (this.height / 100 * this.height / 100), outMass);
    };

  }]);
```

And my factory (conversion.js):

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Conversion', [])
    .factory('weightConverter', function() {
        var mases  = ['kg', 'lb'];
        var kgToLb = {
            kg: 1,
            lb: 2.2046226
        };
        var convertMass =  function (amount, outMass) {
            return amount * kgToLb[outMass];
        };

        return {
            mases: mases,
            convertMass: convertMass
        };
    });
```

And the app.js:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name measureBmiApp
 * @description
 * # measureBmiApp
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
angular
  .module('measureBmiApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: store a variable reference to `this` just inside controller, then use that variable inside `total()` . Looks like a scope problem using `this`. Check for erros thrown also

Comment: Yes, i get this error:

 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module measureBmiApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Conversion due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'Conversion' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

But everything is spelled correct.

Comment: Make sure you have included conversion.js as well along with main.js. That is what it looks like the issue is otherwise it just works fine.  http://plnkr.co/edit/nkQAz6RlzJ037WMkUH2q?p=preview @charlietfl There should n't be a context issue here. OP is using controller alias syntax.

Comment: that error will also show up if you have syntax errors breaking inside that module. Check loading order of scripts also

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers - i apologize for being such a newbie, but still can't figure it out. I have just updated the question with a fourth file (app.js). I have installed Angular via Yeoman which includes the files in the app.js file.
Should i include the conversion.js in the app.js?
I thought it should be included i my MainController.

Comment: @RicoRosenkrans In your app.js you have not listed the dependecy on `Conversion` module. It was there in your first example though. it should be simple enough to see if conversion.js has been loaded at all by looking at the network console.

Comment: Im sorry, but i still gets this error:
 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module measureBmiApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Conversion due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'Conversion' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

conversion.js

```
angular.module('measureBmiApp')
    .factory('weightConverter', ['weightConverter', function(weightConverter) {
    'use strict';
    var mases  = ['kg', 'lb'];
    var kgToLb = {
        kg: 1,
        lb: 2.2046226
    };
    var convertMass =  function (amount, outMass) {
        return amount * kgToLb[outMass];
    };

    return {
        mases: mases,
        convertMass: convertMass
    };
}]);
```

main.js

```
angular.module('measureBmiApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['weightConverter', function(weightConverter) {
    'use strict';
    this.height = 180;
    this.weight = 90; 
    this.inMass = 'kg';
    this.mases  = weightConverter.mases;

    this.total = function total(outMass) {
        return weightConverter.convertMass(this.weight / (this.height / 100 * this.height / 100), outMass);
    };

}]);
```

app.js

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name measureBmiApp
 * @description
 * # measureBmiApp
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
angular
  .module('measureBmiApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

Comment: Im sorry, but i still gets this error:
 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module measureBmiApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Conversion due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'Conversion' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: why you have multiple modules? measureBmiApp and Conversion

Comment: I have updated the answer, did you have a chance to look at it?

Comment: Hi Huan, thank you very much for taking the time. I just tried the new code, but unfortunately the input fields are still empty.
But should 'weightConverter' be placed 3 times on the second line in conversion.js?
Should it not have it's own name as well?
Thank you once again.